# IOError [Errno 21] Is a directory: u'<path to templates>'

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have been working with Django 1.6. Everything working fine. Recently, I found that later versions of Django have better features and hence upgraded my django using `pip install -U Django`. It got updraded to 1.10.6. Now I am getting this error. (with `DEBUG=True`)

```
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value: [Errno 21] Is a directory: u'<absolute_path_to_templates>'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py in get_contents, line 24
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

And this:

```
Error during template rendering
In template <path_to_template>/code1.html, error at line 1
1   {% extends "code2.html" %}
```

Did I miss anything that is to be done after upgrading Django to 1.10.6 ? BTW, If I run with `DEBUG = False`, it does launch the app but my static files (js,css,images) are not getting loaded and also the UI is a bit distorted. Does Django 1.10.6 has different way of loading static files as compared to Django 1.6 ? Does extends have a different syntax in 1.10.6. I did google a lot didn't find anything useful for my case.

My settings.py has this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "<absolute path to static filesfolder>/static"
```

Following some suggestion online, I tried adding `STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR,'static')` instead. Earlier I was very clear about loading static files. But now I am confused again.

My template settings(polls is my app name - I am following the official Django site and am using same names):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['<path_till_mysite>/mysite/polls/templates','<path_till_mysite>/mysite/polls/templates/polls'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I suggest you to upgrade gradually. E.g. 1.6->1.7->1.8->1.9->1.10.
This is much less painful and easy.

Comment: Your static settings have nothing to do with this; you need to show your template settings.

Comment: I am now trying with 1.8.17. It says `<path_till_mysite>/mysite/polls/templates (Not a file)`. It obviously is not a file. That is just the directory where my templates would be there. Why is it seeing `templates` as a file ?